# Froala Editor is not functioning Properly in web components like toolbar buttons, character count

Tags: web-component, froala

https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/f0b2b4d58c301ec2586228d8f379d95e

Bold Italic shortcuts are working but not the toolbar buttons.
But everything is working fine in standalone html.

Comment: Do you really need that shadowDom? I don't think so. Just create a web component without a shadowDom and it should be working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `fullPage: true` option inside the config of Froala, the toolbar buttons work again. https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options/#fullPage

You can also have a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ilyasfroaal/ypbLok4r/7/